# How to automatically deploy a Laravel app with embedded Angular to Heroku

Tags: angular, heroku, laravel-5

I have a test app in GIT which has Laravel project and Angular SPA.

I have webpack, which builds the angular app and copies its files to `/public/` folder of Laravel. To build angular, I run command `npm run build`

I have successfully deployed my *laravel app* to heroku but I am unable to deploy angular part correctly. I just need that during the deployment process on Heroku dyno it runs also a command like following

```
cd angular-app && npm run build
```

I have seen few tutorials and they talk about using nodejs server on Heroku. But I do not understand why I would need Node server on heroku when Nginx with Laravel will deliver all contents. I just need the angular app to be compiled.

Is there a way to run build commands on PHP, Nginx, Laravel dyno in Heroku?

Please help.

My Procfile (*name of the file which Heroku uses*) is

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx  public/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple build packs in Heroku, this way your app will be first built by one build pack and then by the second one.

It is a great solution if you have an app with ruby and angular or PHP and angular.

Read more about it using this link:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app

I cannot believe that no one here told me this for last 3 days. I finally found the correct answer and am editing by reply regarding using CircleCI.